# Extract internal hyperlink from xlsx workbook

Tags: r

I have an input xlsx workbook with many (thousands) **internal** hyperlinks to many other sheets (in the same workbook). A small, representative example at [xlsx image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00A6L.jpg):  "A2" links to "linksTab!B3".  [xlsx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sfuue17kvblnmo/small_link.xlsx?dl=0) itself here on dropbox.

which I can access (Based on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152082/9038929)) using

```
library(XML)

# rename file to .zip
my.zip.file <- sub("xlsx", "zip", my.excel.file)
file.copy(from = my.excel.file, to = my.zip.file)

# unzip the file
unzip(my.zip.file)

# unzipping produces a bunch of files which we can read using the XML package
# sheet1 has our data
xmlfile <- xmlParse("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml")
```

However, the final xml extraction in referenced question output yields an empty output in this case. Digging into the XML sheet1, I found that the links are represented in the xml file as

> < hyperlink ref="A2" location="linksTab!B3" tooltip="goto link"
>   display="link" xr:uid="{94...'

How do I extract them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer:
Once the xmlfile is loaded as per above, get the links via

```
# grab the hyperlinks, and dump the XML components by convert them to character vector
 linkReferences <- tibble(
     RefCell  = as.character( xpathApply(xmlfile, "//x:hyperlink/@ref",      namespaces="x")),
     LinkCell = as.character( xpathApply(xmlfile, "//x:hyperlink/@location", namespaces="x"))
 )

 linkReferences  
 # A tibble: 5 x 2
   RefCell    LinkCell
     <chr>       <chr>
 1      A2 linksTab!B3
 2   A3:A5 linksTab!B3
 3      A3 linksTab!D3
 4      A4 linksTab!F3
 5      A5 linksTab!H3
```