# How to read the external excel workbooks inside Formulas using R?

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I would like to read the formulas inside a workbook using R. I have an excel file called "link.xlsx" with value 1 at cell A1 and another excel file called "myFile.xlsx" with value A1=[link.xlsx]Tabelle1!$A$1. I tried the following:

```
library('XLConnect')

wb<-loadWorkbook("myFile.xlsx")

getCellFormula(wb,1,1,1)
```

I get

```
[1]Tabelle1!$A$1
```

and not

`[link.xlsx]Tabelle1!$A$1`.

1) How I can fix the problem?

2)Is there a way to quickly get the list of external reference workbooks (linked excels) using R?

**UPDATE:** For the moment, I found a solution using the approach explained here:

[Extract hyperlink from Excel file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149821/extract-hyperlink-from-excel-file-in-r)

but I still wonder if it is possible to solve the problem into a more compact way.