Read an Excel file which contains hyperlinks
I need to read an excel file into R.
I am using the following code:
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("path/to/file.xlsx")

The Excel file looks like this:

I would like to read the file into R so that the URLs behind the hyperlinks are also read into R. Currently, only the text is being read in, not the URLs.
So, the resulting data frame should look something like this:
print(data)

| id | link_text | link_url          |
|----|-----------|-------------------|
| 1  | link1     | www.google.com    |
| 2  | link2     | www.amazon.com    |
| 3  | link3     | www.bing.com      |
| 4  | link4     | www.apple.com     |
| 5  | link5     | www.microsoft.com |


This answer solves your problem, you just have to run extract_hyperlinks_from_excel("path/to/file.xlsx"), make sure you copy-paste and run the function code.

AFAIK not really trivial, but take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013136/extract-hyperlink-from-excel-cell-that-has-text-that-is-hyperlinked

While the linked answer gets OP most of the way there, it does not provide a solution as to how to join the hyperlink data to the sheet data.

@the-mad-statter - I agree, it's also a very janky and inelegant solution - As mentioned above, I can't really find a non-trivial way to do this, so for the time being I've turned to Python. pretty unfortunate really :(
