# Extract URLs from hyperlinks

Tags: r, csv, url, hyperlink

I have an excel file with a column that contains several hyperlinks. I would like to import the file as a dataframe and create a new column that contains the URLs from every hyperlink. It’s posible to do this using R?

Thank you!

I tried importing the file, but since there I’m in a dead spot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24152082/8245406) is helpful.